# How do I see the connections between abelian/non-abelian group and their gauge transformations?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, group-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

I'm learning QED in my QFT class without too much background in group theory. Recently I'm introduced to the Abelian gauge transformation

$$
D_\mu\psi(x)\rightarrow e^{i\alpha(x)}D_\mu\psi(x)\quad
A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A_\mu(x)-\frac{1}{e}\partial_\mu\alpha(x)
$$
and non-abelian gauge transformation
$$
D_\mu\psi(x)\rightarrow e^{it^a\theta(x)}D_\mu\psi(x)\quad  A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A^a_\mu(x)+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu\alpha^a(x) +f^{abc}A^b_\mu\alpha^c
$$

A group is called abelian if all its elements commute between themselves, otherwise the group is non-abelian. My question is are there any direct connections between (non)abelian group and (non)abelian transformations?

Comment: If you set $f^{abc}=0$ in the non-abelian one, you get a decoupled collection of abelian ones...

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos
 Thanks, what do you mean by 'decoupled collection'?

Comment: It means a set of abelian transformations completely independent of each other, except their electric charges are identical; which you may change without consequences to the consistency of the theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a connection, as Cosmmas mentions in his comment they are related by setting $f^{abc}$ to zero. To go into a little bit of detail in gauge theory we are normally considering continuous groups (though one can define gauge theories with finite groups as well). These groups are often so called Lie groups i.e. finite dimensional groups that have a manifold structure. If this is the case they permit a lie algebra which through the exponential map generates (a part) of the group. This algebra is described by its Lie bracket $[-,-]$. For example if you take the group $U(n)$ then the corresponding lie algebra consists of all antihermitian matrices (assuming the convention that $A = e^{X}$ for $A \in U(n)$ and $X$ in the algebra. Here the Lie bracket is just the known commutator of matrices. Now how we see weather a group is abelian or not depends on the structure of this bracket. What one does is take a basis of the algebra $T^a$, so called generators, and looks at the commutation relation of these basis elements. As the resulting object still has to reside within the algebra, one can again write this in the basis $T^a$ such that

$[T^a,T^b] = f^{abc}T_c$ where we sum over $c$. Now the choice of naming these so called structure constants as I have here is no coincidence as they are exactly what shows up in your definition of the transformation of a gauge field. Now this story is true for all Lie groups abelian and not abelian. However it turns out (by some basic algebra) that if the group is indeed abelian, that only one generator exists (This is actually wrong, of course one could take a group like $U(1) \times U(1)$ however the algebra decomposes trivially so that we can look at each factor independently, where we mean that the algebra is a direct sum.) and as such the bracket is trivial as $[T,T] = 0$. Thus all structure constants are zero as well.

To go a step further, the reason why $A$ carries an index is that this objects lives in the algebra i.e. generally $A = A^a T_a$. From this you can actually derive the transformation property of $A$ directly by defining wilson line operators and with those the covariant derivative and imposing that this actually transforms covariantly.